Unable to use getSymbols in for loop and call matrix after
I have a list of the top 25 most popular ETFs. I want to make a for loop that takes in each entry of this list and uses the getSymbol() function from the quantmod library and returns the data called. When I try, all that happens is the entry from the list gets printed.
This is my code.
`top25_ETFS <- c("SPY", "IVV", "VOO", "VTI", "QQQ", "VEA", "VUG","VTV",
                "IEFA","BND","AGG","IWF","IJH","IJR","VIG","IEMG"
                ,"VWO","VXUS","VGT","IWM","XLK","VO","GLD","VB","SCHD",)
for (i in 1:1) {
  etf <- getSymbols(top25_ETFS[i], src = "yahoo")
  etf_returns <- ROC(etf$.Adjusted, type = 'discrete')
}`

This is the output when printing "etf"
`[1] "SPY"`

This is the output when printing "etf_returns"
`Error in etf$etf.Adjusted : $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors`

I'm not sure how to store the actual data in the variable etf and then find its returns from this etf variable. I want to be able to make a for loop that can automate the process for all 25 ETFs

Regarding terminology quantmod is a package, not a library.  A library is a directory holding a set of packages.  Admittedly this is confusing owing to the name of the library function.

This loops through the ETFs (for the reprex just the first 6) and uses auto.assign = FALSE to capture the actual data in a list.
bind_rows() is used to create a dataframe consolidating the data for all tickers. Then grouping by ticker, the return percentage may be calculated as the current day's adjusted price over the previous day's price - 1.
library(quantmod)
library(tidyverse)

top25_ETFS <- c(
  "SPY", "IVV", "VOO", "VTI", "QQQ", "VEA", "VUG", "VTV",
  "IEFA", "BND", "AGG", "IWF", "IJH", "IJR", "VIG", "IEMG",
  "VWO", "VXUS", "VGT", "IWM", "XLK", "VO", "GLD", "VB", "SCHD"
)

lst <- vector("list", length(top25_ETFS))

# only 1:6 for the reprex
for (i in 1:6) {
  lst[[i]] <- getSymbols(top25_ETFS[i], src = "yahoo", auto.assign = FALSE) |>
    as_tibble(rownames = "date") |>
    rename_with(\(x) str_remove(x, top25_ETFS[i])) |>
    mutate(date = ymd(date))
}

names(lst) <- top25_ETFS

df <- lst |>
  bind_rows(.id = "ticker") |>
  mutate(return = .Adjusted / lag(.Adjusted) - 1, .by = ticker)

head(df)
#> # A tibble: 6 × 9
#>   ticker date       .Open .High  .Low .Close  .Volume .Adjusted    return
#>   <chr>  <date>     <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl>    <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>
#> 1 SPY    2007-01-03  142.  143.  141.   141. 94807600      102. NA       
#> 2 SPY    2007-01-04  141.  142.  141.   142. 69620600      102.  0.00212 
#> 3 SPY    2007-01-05  141.  141.  140.   141. 76645300      101. -0.00798 
#> 4 SPY    2007-01-08  141.  141.  140.   141. 71655000      101.  0.00462 
#> 5 SPY    2007-01-09  141.  142.  140.   141. 75680100      101. -0.000850
#> 6 SPY    2007-01-10  141.  142.  140.   142. 72428000      102.  0.00333

Created on 2024-04-07 with reprex v2.1.0

This fixed the issue for me. I'm able to use the loop on all ETFs like I wanted. Thanks for your help.

To keep the example small we will use just two ETFs but the same code works for any number. Now, using the list of xts objects L2 from my previous answer this uses Ad making a list of the Adjusted columns as xts objects and then applies ROC to each giving a list of xts objects each representing the ROCs of one ETF.  Finally merge them into a single xts object, roc. If what you wanted is a list of xts objects omit the last line (marked ##).
Note that using explicit loops unnecessarily is generally regarded as undesirable and this code avoids that and is compact.
roc <- L2 |>
  lapply(Ad) |>
  lapply(ROC, type = "discrete") |>
  do.call("merge", args = _) ##

# check

tail(roc)
##             VOO.Adjusted  VTI.Adjusted
## 2024-03-27  0.0087285011  0.0088169798
## 2024-03-28 -0.0001247973  0.0006544600
## 2024-04-01 -0.0013105988 -0.0007694563
## 2024-04-02 -0.0065407432 -0.0092415260
## 2024-04-03  0.0009015845  0.0015547005
## 2024-04-04 -0.0123176943 -0.0119907313

If you want a long form data.frame then
long <- fortify.zoo(roc, melt = TRUE)

# check

tail(long)
##           Index       Series         Value
## 6825 2024-03-27 VTI.Adjusted  0.0088169798
## 6826 2024-03-28 VTI.Adjusted  0.0006544600
## 6827 2024-04-01 VTI.Adjusted -0.0007694563
## 6828 2024-04-02 VTI.Adjusted -0.0092415260
## 6829 2024-04-03 VTI.Adjusted  0.0015547005
## 6830 2024-04-04 VTI.Adjusted -0.0119907313


Got it. Thanks for your help, your code is much clearer.
